# Como usar tipo "BigInteger" para resolver esse problema?

Tags: java

Estou resolvendo uma solução baseado na história envolvendo o tabuleiro de xadrez. Veja um pedaço da história:

> "Então Sessa pediu seu pagamento em grão de trigo da seguinte maneira:
>   Um grão de trigo pela primeira casa do tabuleiro, dois pela segunda,
>   quatro pela terceira, e assim dobrando até a sexagésima quarta e
>   última casa do tabuleiro.
>
> Qual o total de grãos?"

Comecei o código assim:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Graos {

    // Só consegui até este método 
    public static BigInteger numeroGraos(BigInteger totalGraos) {

        //nao sei o que por aqui e retornar.

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

       int i=1;
       int grao=1;

       for (i=1; i<=64; i++) {

           totalGraos+=grao;

           grao=(grao*2); //o quadro seguinte é duas vezes o anterior (PG).
       }

       System.out.println ("O total de grãos é " + totalGraos);
    }
 }
```

Se usar inteiro para o total de grãos, ultrapassará o tamanho do tipo `int`.

Já testei `i` com limite menor e funcionou. O detalhe é só no `BigInt`.

Como procedo daqui em diante?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se entendi corretamente a sua dúvida,

Segue o que entendi o que você quer fazer:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Graos {
    
     public static BigInteger numeroGraos(int casasDoTabuleiro) {    
         // Inciamos com zero 
         BigInteger numerosDeGrao = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);
         // Inciamos com 1 grão ...
         BigInteger quantidadeDeGrao = BigInteger.valueOf(1L);
         
         int ponteiro = 0;
         
         for (ponteiro=1; ponteiro<=casasDoTabuleiro; ponteiro++) {
             
             // somamos o numeroDeGrao com a quantidadeDeGrao, passando a soma para a variável!
             numerosDeGrao =  numerosDeGrao.add( quantidadeDeGrao  );
             // Multiplicamos a quantidadeDeGrao por 2!
             quantidadeDeGrao =  quantidadeDeGrao.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2L) )  ;
             
         }
            
         return numerosDeGrao;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        BigInteger total = numeroGraos(64);
        System.out.println("Total: "+total);
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, as duas respostas parecidas, mas que ajudaram bastante.

Answer (score 10):

Aquele método não é 100% necessário, você pode usar o tipo BigInteger no lugar do int, a diferença é que o BigInteger é uma classe e seus objetos são imutáveis, e os seus métodos retornam um valor, sem alterar o objeto que chamou o método, isso torna um pouco chatinho de trabalhar com ele, mas resolve o seu problema.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Graos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger grao = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        BigInteger totalGraos = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

        for (int i=1; i<=64; i++) { 
            totalGraos = totalGraos.add(grao);
            grao = grao.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        }   
        System.out.println ("O total de grãos é " + totalGraos);    
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> O total de grãos é 18446744073709551615

Answer (score 2):

## Não precisa fazer um *loop*

Dá para resolver com um cálculo simples, sem precisar de *loop*.

No fundo estamos trabalhando com potências de 2, o que facilita bastante o cálculo.

Primeiro vamos ver quantos grãos estão em cada casa do tabuleiro:

| Nº da casa | Quantidade de grãos desta casa |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 = 2<sup>0</sup> |
| 2 | 2 = 2<sup>1</sup> |
| 3 | 4 = 2<sup>2</sup> |
| 4 | 8 = 2<sup>3</sup> |
| n | 2<sup>n - 1</sup> |

Então para saber o total de grãos para N casas, basta somar as potências de 2, com o expoente indo de zero até N - 1. E já tem uma fórmula que faz isso:

2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + … + 2<sup>n - 1</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1

Ou seja, para as 64 casas do tabuleiro, temos que N=64, e portanto o total de grãos é 2<sup>64</sup> - 1. Usando `BigInteger` ficaria assim:

```java
// para 64 casas, total de grãos é 2⁶⁴ - 1
BigInteger totalGraos = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(64).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
System.out.println("O total de grãos é " + totalGraos);
```

Comment: Essa reposta deveria ser marcada como a correta,pois é a mais eficiente.